# "Unable to open: File is a directory" when importing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

I'm working on a React project in vscode. I noticed a few days ago that any of my imports that point to a directory with an index.js/jsx file in them cannot be resolved by cmd+clicking on the import or the function name.

I get an error in the bottom right "Unable to open : File is a directory"

I have the following in my `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "target": "es2017",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

I've tried:

- Removing the jsconfig entirely
- Various combinations of module import/export patterns
- Various combinations of paths/baseUrl/other options in the jsconfig file
- Disabling all extensions

Nothing seems to work. The only way I get cmd+click to work is if I point my imports directly at the component itself, or directly at the `index.js` file.

Does anyone have any insights, please? Googling hasn't shone much light on anything. It's not the end of the world as I cmd+t to most things but it sure is annoying. FWIW Webstorm handles the imports without any issues. Cheers.

[image: file is a directory error message]

EDIT: I forgot to mention. For added spiciness, the cmd+click works for a few seconds while vscode loads. Then "something" happens and it starts throwing the error. Other projects seem to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have solved it by adding a `tsconfig.json` to the project root with the same `paths` etc. I can now reliably click on import and see function definitions on hover.

If anyone has a similar problem, try the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/**.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Adding `"moduleResolution": "node",` fixed it for me.

I have jsconfig.json with these values:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src/",
        "module": "esnext"
    },
    "include": ["src", "public/workers/worker.js"]
}
```